# PHP time not converting/saving correctly

Tags: php, date, time

Probably a simple one here although running out of ideas!

I have a simple calculation for times;

`$total_hours_work_cal = ($end_time_name - $start_time_name - $total_break_name);`

This does bring back the correct value, take the following for example;

- Start time = 08:00
- End Time = 12:00

The value returned is 4, which I'd expect to save as 04:00 although it's simply saving it as 4 which then displays in my database as 00:00:04.000000.

I need it to display in the database as 04:00:00.000000 but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

```
$startTime = new DateTime("$start_time_name");
$endTime = new DateTime("$end_time_name");
$endTime->sub(date_interval_create_from_date_string("$total_break_name"));
$interval = date_diff($endTime, $startTime);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S'), PHP_EOL;
```

The calculation for this would be;

- End time = 10:00
- Start Time = 05:00
- Break Time = 00:30

But it just returns 05:00 as opposed to the expected 04:30

Comment: 4 hours != 4 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're trying to explain to me Markus!

Comment: The value 4 is for seconds, not 4 hours. Multiply seconds with 3600 to get hours.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Markus that's fine now! One last thing, any idea why the break time of 0:30 isn't being taken into consideration? the value does get returned but it seems to ignore anything in the calculation below 1:00

Comment: Thanks for upvoting, but please mark the "answer as correct".

Comment: Sorry Markus, thought I did that - done now, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 4 is for seconds, not 4 hours. Multiply seconds with 3600 to get hours.

But you should better use PHP internals date functions.

```php
$startTime = new DateTime('08:00');
$endTime = new DateTime('12:00');
$endTime->sub(date_interval_create_from_date_string('10 minutes'));
$interval = date_diff($endTime, $startTime);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S'), PHP_EOL;

$startTime = new DateTime('08:00');
$endTime = new DateTime('12:30');
$endTime->sub(date_interval_create_from_date_string('15 minutes'));
$interval = date_diff($endTime, $startTime);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S'), PHP_EOL;
```

> 03:50:00
>   04:15:00

## Update with break time as time string

We take the end time and subtract the break time from it. From what's left we subtract the start time and get the effective work time.

```
$startTime = new DateTime('08:00');
$endTime = new DateTime('12:30');
$breakTime = new DateTime('00:15');

$breakSubtracted = new DateTime($endTime->diff($breakTime)->format('%H:%I:%S'));
$workTime = date_diff($breakSubtracted, $startTime)->format('%H:%I:%S');
echo $workTime;
```

> 04:15:00

Comment: That works great Markus, thanks a lot - would you perhaps know why it's not taking into consideration a break time of 0:10? It's calculating without subtracting the 0:10

Comment: Thanks for that Markus, although whenever I add new DateTime, it breaks the entire code, nothing is updating or running - any ideas?

Comment: Please give an example. My answer considers your questions context.

Comment: I've made an edit to my original question to show you what your solution returned for me (seems like new DateTime is working now?)

Comment: `$endTime->sub(date_interval_create_from_date_string("$total_break_name"));` Needs to be a Period Text like "10 minutes". BTW, it makes no sense to quote variables.

Comment: I'm not sure how that'd work in my code as the break number is being passed through a form set by users

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus, I've marked this as the answer!